# Disabled touch-ui but unable to find sidekick when i switched to classic-ui

Tags: aem

Is there any way that i can do it for whole site?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far? Please check out the [how to ask help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I tried overlaying the page components. For each if i add slingResourceSuper type wcm/foundation/components/page. It is appearing. But i want the whole demo site to have that feature.

Answer (score 0):

For individual user instance, Go to user account settings > Preferences > Author mode, select classicUI

more info here: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-3/author/author-environment/user-properties.html#Account Settings

Alternatively, to have all users of an AEM instance use the Classic UI by default, start off by going to the AEM Web Console Configuration (/system/console/configMgr).  Make sure you’re signed in as an admin and do a find for “WCM Authoring UI Mode Service.”  If the service is not visible, click on the OSGi button at the top followed by Configuration, and then do another find.  Click on “WCM Authoring UI Mode Service” and change the “Default authoring UI mode” to “CLASSIC” (or back again to “TOUCH,” depending on what you want to do).  You must enter “CLASSIC” or “TOUCH” in uppercase letters or an error message will show up when opening a site.  Changing this setting will make the chosen UI the default for all sites of the AEM instance.  When opening a site with /siteadmin, or /sites.html/content, the site should now open using the Classic UI.  This should be the case for all users.